# SQL: exclude users based on specific conditions

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery

I am trying to exclude specific users that have only purchased desks from our databases. My current table looks like the following:

| user | item |
| --- | --- |
| a1 | desk |
| a2 | sofa |
| a2 | desk |
| a3 | couch |
| a3 | dinner table |
| a3 | desk |
| a4 | desk |
| a5 | sofa |

So basically, I am trying to exclude only users a1 and a4 because they have only purchased a desk and nothing else. The users a2 and a3 don't need to be removed because they have purchased other furnitures too. Can anyone help me to write the query necessary to remove these users?

This table is so large and unfortunately, I cannot just exclude users manually in the "where" clause.
Thank you!

Comment: `select * 
from t
where user not in (
  select user
  from (
    select user, count(case when item = 'desk' then 1 end) as desks, 
    count(case when item <> 'desk' then 1 end) as other
    from t
    group by user
  ) x
  where desks > 0 and other = 0
) y`

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach

```
select *
from your_table
where true
qualify countif(item != 'desk') over(partition by user) > 0
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]